# At what rate does the volume (velocity) of a note decay?

Tags: piano, midi, sound, digital-piano, midi-controller-keyboard

Forgive me if this is more a physics question than a music question! My question is: When a note is struck on a piano and held down (or a tuning fork is struck, or any instrument where there is just a one-time impact that then rings until dampened), what is the rate of decay in volume (aka velocity)? I strongly suspect that it is not linear; that the volume after two seconds is not half the volume after one second.

By extension, is it possible to calculate, or even just estimate, how long a note continues to reverberate on a piano if struck at maximum impact, versus lightly pressed, when held down in both cases?

**Background, not essential:**

I have a beautiful [AvantGrand N2](https://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical_instruments/pianos/avantgrand/n2/index.html), which includes a standard MIDI output via a [UX16](https://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical_instruments/keyboards/accessories/ux16/index.html) capble that allows one to record on a computer when and how forcefully a note was struck. While MIDI will never capture the complete soul of a piano, I want to use this just to see how accurately I'm expressing certain notes in a chord versus others.

The way MIDI works, it just sends a signal when a note was struck and how forcefully (known as "velocity"), and a second signal when that note was released, even if one removes one's finger 30 seconds later, long after the note has decayed. (It can read the pedals too, but that's a future endeavor.) So my question is: When a note is struck, and I want to visualize the velocity over time, what sort of function should I apply to the initial velocity?

Thank you!

Comment: It's nowhere near that simple. Quick experiment. hit the top note & bottom note... which decays first?

Comment: "what is the rate of decay in volume (aka velocity)?"

For a start, volume isn't velocity.

Comment: @Tetsujin Great little demonstration!

Comment: @LaurencePayne out of curiosity, any idea why the (much criticized) MIDI specs describe the force of the key strike as "velocity"? The same term applies to the depth of the dampening pedal touch and various other measures

Comment: Velocity is basically how **fast** you hit the note. The way the sensors work that's all it can do - times how long it takes for the note to travel from rest to pressed. That is translated to 'weight'. Once the note is then generated, real or imaginary, what you then hear is 'volume'.

Comment: Velocity is "the rate at which a keyboard controller key is pressed" according to a paper about how to interpret and implement it.  https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/92a7/dc5007d770e0c5a3a637f66ee128ba107a92.pdf

Comment: Once you're in the realm of actual sound, midi then has no job to do until you let go of the note, at which point the processor then determines what should occur [good ones have all kinds of ancillary functions at that point - sympathetic resonance, mechanical noise, subtle stuff, but that's why the Avants are  expensive]

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, the Avant delivers a "Polyphonic Aftertouch" (midi code 10100000/A0/160 for Channel 1), which I'm still figuring out

Comment: Not sure how much use that's ever going to be for a piano, but it's useful in synthesis & sound manipulation. Check your midi recorder can record it [many don't by default], but only if you can find a real use for it, as it's data intensive.

Comment: You're using a synth (hence the MIDI output) - this is not an acoustic piano so far as I can tell from the ad blurb.  The decay is thus determined with a bunch of algorithms and the prerecorded sound samples.

Comment: You hit the key with force.  The result of the force is to give the key movement velocity.  And, whether it's an acoustic piano or a MIDI keyboard, the velocity is what matters.   In a piano the hammer is thrown at the string.  Like a baseball once it's left the pitcher's hand, the only information the batter receives is its (fixed) mass and its velocity.  And the MIDI keyboard simply measures elapsed time from the top of the key travel to the bottom.   I.e. the velocity.   Some MIDI controls that are just switches use nominal velocity values - perhaps 0 for off, 64 for on - for convenience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You needn't calculate or estimate or do fancy math.  Others have [measured](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/10.1121/1.1935148) piano string decay rates, and they're messy:

> Measurements have been made on a high‐quality spinet piano to determine the initial amplitude and decay characteristics of the principal harmonic components of notes covering the entire scale. Decay rates of individual components varied from 1 to 100 db/sec as a function principally of frequency and string position in the scale rather than of harmonic number. An exception was noted in the third to fifth octaves, where the fundamental of a given string decayed at a considerably higher rate than the harmonics. This pattern appears to have a strong influence in determining typical piano tone in this region. Frequency spectra of the initial amplitudes of individual notes over the entire scale show, on the average, a sharp cutoff below 100 cps, a fairly flat region between 100 and 1000 cps, and a roll‐off of at least 12 db per octave above 1000 cps, with negligible energy above 8000 cps.

Here's another technical [paper](http://matthiasmauch.de/_pdf/cheng2015modelling.pdf) whose abstract confirms your hunch that the decay is nonlinear.

Comment: Thank you! Seeing as I'm not trying to recreate a realistic piano from mere MIDI, this will suffice just fine. Thank you!